# where should I store morilog/jalai package?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have downloaded morilog/jalali package for date and time in laravel framework, Which directory is proper to add it?
any one help me

Comment: It seems you've added a lot of tags that aren't necessary relevant - if you're question is about adding a package in general it doesn't matter  if it's a `date`, `time`, `calendar` etc. It's more important to tag the language and the framework you are using

Comment: How did you download it? Usually, `composer install`  takes care of everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add it (and download it) using The **Composer** :
go to your project directory and use composer like this:

```
composer require morilog/jalali:3.*
```

in addition, Composer will download it into `/vendor/` directory and it will update your `autoload` .